# Concave Differential Inequality

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis

I got this homework in the calculus class, but I haven't been able to solve it. Please, any help will be great!

Let $g(x):[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ such that $g(x)$ is increasing and concave and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Find all the $g(x)$ functions such that $\forall c\in[0,\infty)$ it is true that $ g''(x+c)x+g'(x+c)<1/n $

Is easy to check that any linear function $g(x)=a+bx:1/n> b\ge0$ works. But I don't know how to prove that these are the only functions that satisfy this condition.

Thanks!

Note: Sorry for the typos, is the first time I write here... I hope there aren't other typos.

Comment: What is $n$? Is it related to $c$ or to anything else here?

Comment: Sorry, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, I already adjusted in the heading. Thanks!

Comment: What if we define $f : [0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ as $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}},& 0\leq x\leq 1 \\ 0,& x > 1 \end{cases}$$ Then, we let $g'(x) = \int_x^1 f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$. Therefore, $g'\geq 0$ and $g''\leq 0$. This implies that for any $x\in (1, \infty)$ or $c\in (1-x, \infty)$, $h(x, c) = g''(x+c)x+g'(x+c) = 0$. Therefore, we only need consider $(x, c)$ such that $x\in [0, 1]$ and $c\in [0, 1-x]$. Since this set is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $h$ is continuous, $h(x, c)$ is bounded above by some $M > 0$. All we need to do is multiply $g'$ by positive $k < \frac{1}{Mn}$.

Comment: This counterexample show that not all solutions are linear. Even if you add the conditions of _strict_ increasingness and concavity, we can modify the example slightly, adding an integrable function that decays faster than $\frac{1}{x}$ to $g''$ outside of $[0, a]$ for some $a < 1$, and increasing $g'$ by the integral of this function. Then, we will have $g'' < 0$ and $g' > 0$.

Comment: More generally, we can let $g''$ be any compactly supported, bounded, nonpositive function, and then add a displacement to $g'$ so that it's compactly supported and nonnegative. Multiplying by some positive constant $k$ will give us a $g$ that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Very nice construction. But then, do you think it is possible to characterize all the functions that work?

Comment: I would doubt that there's any easy, closed-form solution, anyway. Any function in $C_c^0([0, \infty))$ can be adapted to fit our conditions for $g''$.

Comment: @MichaelLee  in your example $g$ is only increasing on interval $[0,1]$.....

Comment: Depends on your definition of "increasing." This is often taken to mean "nowhere decreasing," with "strictly increasing" meaning "increasing everywhere." However, I address this in the follow-up comment, in which I say that it doesn't really matter, and we can modify the example slightly to fit either definition.

Comment: Considering that the original poster stated $g(x) = a$ as an example, I assume that their definition is the one I used.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what kind of characterization you looking for but one possible characterization is as follow :

Your conditions are equivalent to $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty) $ with $g'' \leq0$ and $ 0 < g' < \frac{1}{n}$.

beside that above itself can be consider as a characterization, you can get another characterization in terms of $g$ not its derivatives which is

$g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is increasing , concave function **strictly** dominated by the line $$y= \frac{1}{n} x + g(0) $$

Comment: I might add that _any_ concave, increasing function $g$ can be made to be strictly dominated by a linear function of any slope $m$ by ensuring that $g'(0) < m$.

Comment: @MichaelLee  True,  actually what you mentioned is true for any concave function , it doesn't need to be increasing or even differentiable ...

Comment: Sure, I was just speaking about the functions that might solve this particular problem.